# error: Cannot find symbol variable rand

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am very new here, and I am following this course on Udemy, which is making a project called "Higher or Lower". I wrote this code, and I keep getting this error which says:

```
error: Cannot find symbol variable rand
```

Here is my code:

```
package com.harimahmed.higherorlower;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int randomNumber;

public void guess(View view) {

    EditText guessEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.guessEditText);

    int guessInt = Integer.parseInt(guessEditText.getText().toString());

    if (guessInt > randomNumber) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Lower!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else if (guessInt < randomNumber) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Higher!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {

        Toast.makeText(this, "That's it! Play again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        randomNumber = rand.nextInt(20) + 1;
    }

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Random rand = new Random();
    randomNumber = rand.nextInt(20) + 1;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: `rand` is a local variable in `onCreate()`, it's inaccessible in `guess()`

Answer (score 0):

**You can make `rand` as global variable .**

1.Use `private Random rand;` outside of `onCreate()` method

2.You can initialize the data `rand = new Random();` in the `onCreate()` method .

3.Then you can call it in the other place  .

3.
try

```
private Random rand;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    rand = new Random();
    randomNumber = rand.nextInt(20) + 1;
}
```